# Spinnaker authentication using IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, in-app-purchase, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

We are trying to enable authentication in Spinnaker using IAP.

- Spinnaker is deployed in GKE using HAL
- Deck and Gate are exposed to different domains using Ingress and HTTPS is enabled for both.
- IAP is enabled and credential is created.
- HAL configurations for IAP have been done and redeployed. BaseURLs for UI & API have been set.
- CORS pattern is set to the UI URL.

Now when i try to open the application, initially the redirects to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?.... fails a few times (CORS error) before sending me to the log in page. Once logged in, my name appears in the welcome page of Spinnaker. After this stage all API (Gate) calls are failing with CORS error (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://spinnaker-api.abc.com/webhooks/preconfigured' from origin 'https://spinnaker.abc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.). Same is the issue with Applications call as well.

We have set the baseURLs for UI as well as API. So ideally CORS should have been taken care of.

When I hit https://spinnaker-api.abc.com/applications directly from the browser, I am getting a 200 response.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How you are implementing IAP? Are you using any Cloud storage as a  persistence store? If yes, what is the permission that is provided in the Cloud Storage?

Comment: @shamma the cluster has some persistent disks attached to it. but the spinnaker deployments/pods don't have any volumes mounted. We could find any documentation which tells exactly how to configure IAP. So we took inputs from multiple sources. Spinnaker is deployed using HAL and is exposed using Ingress and Nodeports to two domain names. IAP is enabled from the console and HAL is used to enable IAP in Spinnaker.

Comment: In order to reproduce the issue, I need more details about your setup. Can you please share the multiple sources you mentioned to use for guidance? Can you provide the full CORS error that you are receiving?

Comment: I used the below info: -  https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto     - https://github.com/spinnaker/halyard/blob/master/docs/commands.md#hal-config-security-authn-iap

Comment: CORS is currently not supported with cloud IAP. That is why, you are getting this error.You may file a public issue to request [https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers] CORS support to be added.

Comment: is there a workaround?

Comment: There is a existing feature request for CORS support to IAP [https://issuetracker.google.com/78326322]. The alternative solution is not to use CORS is IAP or if you want to use CORS then try with other oauth solutions other than IAP.

Comment: Hi @Bhavith could you give more details on this? https://community.spinnaker.io/t/spinnaker-authentication-using-iap/1110/4 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it working sometime back. The deck has to be exposed using IAP. Deck has a /gate proxy to gate. Set this as the API baseurl (spinnakergate-domain.com/gate) and it should work.

I had to edit the .hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml file to make /gate proxy available.